# Swift: How to segue between view controllers and use navigation bar to go backwards within a child view controller (XLPagerTabStrip)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, childviewcontroller, xlpagertabstrip

I am currently implementing the XLPagerTabStrip (https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) which effectively creates a tab bar at the top of the view controller. I want to be able to segue to a new view controller from one of the tabbed controllers and be able to use the navigation bar to move backwards (or a custom version of the navigation bar if this isn't possible).

XLPagerTabStrip provides the `moveToViewController` and `moveToViewControllerAtIndex` functions to navigate between child view controllers, but this method doesn't allow use of a navigation bar to go backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually `XLPagerTabStrip` is a collection of view controllers declared and initialized during the `XLPagerTabStrip` model creation. 
It has virtually no sense to use a `UINavigationController` if you already have all the viewcontrollers available.
You can create a global var `previousIndex` to store the previous viewController index and allow users to go back by using canonical methods:

```
func moveToViewControllerAtIndex(index: Int)
func moveToViewControllerAtIndex(index: Int, animated: Bool)
func moveToViewController(viewController: UIViewController)
func moveToViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
```

About a new viewController, suppose you have 4 viewControllers that built your container (`XLPagerTabStrip`) named for example z1, z2, z3 e z4.
You can embed to z4 a `UINavigationController` (so it have the z4 controller as rootViewController) and start to push or pop your external views. When you want to return to your z4 you can do `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` to your `UINavigationController`

When you are go back to z4 , here you can handle your global var `previousIndex` to moving inside `XLPagerTabStrip`.

Comment: The view controller I want to move to isnt one of the original view controllers within the tabs, but I want to keep the tabs on screen above the new view controller. I was thinking of maybe setting up a new iteration of the XLPagerTabStrip with the destination view controller, and then using a global variable to store the previous index and view controller to navigate back; or is there a simpler way?

Comment: @RyanHampton Did this work out for you? I am dealing with the same issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with XLPagerTabStrip, but I had a similar problem recently and the solution was to use an `unwind segue` to go back to the previous view controller. It's pretty trivial to implement so probably worth a try.

Comment: Hi, this doesnt seem to work, but thanks for taking the time to try and help me!

Answer (score 0):

To navigate back to your previous view tab controller, you had initially  navigated from;

1. Embed your *new view controller*, from which you wish to navigate
   away from in a navigation bar
2. Connect it's Navigation Bar Button to the Parent view containing the
   tab bar by dragging a segue between the 2 views
3. Create a global variable in App delegate to store current index
   which you will use in the Parent view to determine what tab view
   controller to be shown

   `var previousIndex: Int = 0 //0 being a random tab index I have chosen`
4. In your *new view controller*'s (the one you wish to segue from)
   viewdidload function, create an instance of your global variable as
   shown below and assign a value to represent a representative index
   of the child tab bar view controller which houses it.

   ```
   //Global variable instance to set tab index on segue
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
   appDelegate.previousIndex = 2
   ```

You can write this for as many child-tab connected views as you wish, remembering to set the appropriate child-tab index you wish to segue back to

5. Now, create a class property to reference your global variable and a function in your Parent view as shown below

   ```
   let appDelegatefetch = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
   ```

*The function*

```
func moveToViewControllerAtIndex(){
    if (appDelegatefetch.previousIndex == 1){
        self.moveToViewControllerAtIndex((self.appDelegatefetch.previousIndex), animated: false)
    } else if (appDelegatefetch.previousIndex == 2){
        self.moveToViewControllerAtIndex((self.appDelegatefetch.previousIndex), animated: false)
    }
}
```

6. You may now call this function in the Parent View Controller's viewDidLoad, as shown below.

   moveToViewControllerAtIndex()

Run your project and that's it.